# How to iterate through maps & add new layer to data frame and legend of each using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop

Newbie for Python and wondering if the following is doable.

Problem is like this:

I have two sets of data:

1. one mxd file for each of multiple cities (all stored in the same folder) containing links to multiple layers of data.
2. additional dataset (multiple fields; point shapefile) with data for all cities stored in a file geodatabase (*.gdb)

My goal is to have a python script to:

1. open all mxd file iteratively
2. open the additional dataset and select the data based on a query (City name) and add to the mxd file. 
   2) Label the added data in the map by selecting desired field
   2) add the legend of the added data at the bottom of the original legend.

Help with scripting would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do **you** mean by "recursively"? Are you saying that you have one MXD per city and that these are located in lots of different folders that you want to traverse and process?

Comment: Same folder but multiple MXD file. Yes, as you said, one MXD per city.

Comment: I've changed that to say **iteratively** and started to re-format your question to make it clearer but I am confused where it appears to say that you have a point shapefile stored in a file geodatabase.  I've stopped editing it for now - can you perhaps complete the editing because it is, after all, your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using AddLayer, InsertLayer, AddLayerToGroup, etc. from the arcpy.mapping module, but there are some limitations as to what you can do.

For example, unless you have a .lyr file you can apply, there is little control over symbology and labeling.

Also, there isn't a whole lot you can do with the legend other than size, placement, title, and whether or not to auto add new layers. It still might work ok depending on how you set the properties, but you won't be able to manually override any settings. I.e. if the new layers are put in the middle of the list in the ToC, it might be hard to have them display at the bottom of the legend.

So, it's definitely possible, but your mileage may vary.

[AddLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/AddLayer/00s300000025000000/)

[Legend Map Element](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/LegendElement/00s300000041000000/)

Comment: I think this definitely qualifies as an answer rather than a comment (+1).  I'm not sure that I would agree with your statement that "unless you have a .lyr file you can apply, there is little control over symbology and labeling" but some of that extra control came in at 10.1.

Comment: I think there are some tools that give you much more control in 10.1, but as I recall there are still limitations. I think you can set up the kind of symbology (ie Unique Values) but things like color, what symbol to use, size, etc. aren't directly available to python, so pre-existing lyr files are still the only option for changing that kind of stuff. Seems like they're adding more functionality every release though, so someday.